# What does drag lock do in boot camp?

Tags: macos, macbook, boot-camp, touchpad

In the control panel for my mac book pro I have an icon called Boot camp.  Inside there and inside the trackpad tab I have an option called drag lock.

It sounds useful to me as I sometimes find it awkward dragging long distances.  I can't figure out how to use it though.  Can someone explain how I can find out more info on drag lock? I can't find any references on google.

Also even without the dragging option on I can drag.

Comment: BootCamp is a tool that allows you to boot foreign operating systems. What can it share with drag&drop? I don't know.

Comment: @whitequark - It can set the preferences for Apple specific hardware when using Bootcamp.

Comment: @whitequark: Maybe you should take this opportunity to learn not to be rude to people even when you think you are far superior in knowledge. A life lesson.

Comment: One could argue that whitequark wasn't rude, but maybe wrote an unnecessary and uninformative comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained here: https://support.apple.com/guide/bootcamp-control-panel/set-trackpad-options-bcmpa82153f3/mac

You tap the trackpad to highlight, then drag your finger to move the item, then tap again to drop it.

FYI: Googling "What is Apple Drag Lock" produced this result easily.

Comment: I was trying what is boot camp drag lock

Comment: @MacBookNewb - That would be turning drag lock on or off when you're in Bootcamp.

Comment: can you reject my edit actually? I forgot to sign in when I made it and would like to get reputation points for it.